# How to make knockoutJS respond to property changes in real time?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The code bellow is supposed to do the following:

1. When I input a new name, it will show me "Welcome: xxx" in the span.
2. When I delete all the characters in the textbox, nothing will be shown in the span.

The issue is that when I remove one word (suppose the textbox's value is "Bill Gates" in default), and I removed "Gates", I want the span shows me "Bill" in real time not when I leave the field.

**So how to make KnockoutJS support "Real Time" property changes?** I want to see the span changing as I type instead of when leaving the textbox or press the "Enter" key.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Knock Out Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
      Your Name, please: <input type="text" data-bind="value: myName" />
      <br />
      <span data-bind="text: myNameShown, visible: showWelcome" id="spName"></span>
</body>

<script src="KnockOutJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     var model = {
         myName: ko.observable("Bill Gates")
     };

     model.myNameShown = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
         return "Welcome: " + model.myName();
     }, model);

     model.showWelcome = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
         return model.myName() && model.myName().trim() != "";
     }, model);

     ko.applyBindings(model);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: refer to this http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html . cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer by @Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30340405/419956) utilizing `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` in combo with the `value` binding works great, but if you use Knockout 3.2 or higher there's a preferred alternative answer: use [the `textInput` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html). This binding is more succinct, and handles cross-browser quirks. Use it like this:

```js
ko.applyBindings({myName: ko.observable('initial value')});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Input: <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: myName" />
<hr />
Result: <strong data-bind="text: myName"></strong>
```

To quote aforementioned docs about the difference between `textInput` and `value`:

> Although the value binding can also perform two-way binding between text boxes and viewmodel properties, you should prefer textInput whenever you want immediate live updates. The main differences are:
>
> - Immediate updates [...]
> - Browser event quirks handling [...]

Comment: Yes, this is the best answer……

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed this in the doc, thanks for bringing it to my attention :)

Answer (score 2):

To force the binding to update in "real time" or on key press, as opposed to when you leave the control (blur),  Use the binding valueUpdate with "afterkeydown", as explained in the docs here:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

So in your input element you would have to use the binding like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myName, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/luisvsilva/ke22jfa8/1/